# i was creating an image compressor but struggling with startActivityForResult being depricated. looking for a way to solve this startActivityForResult

Tags: android

```
 private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery,
                RESULT_IMAGE);
        
    }
```

this function is not working due to startActivityForResult please suggest some other way

Answer (score 0):

**Register an activity for result:**

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
        // Handle the returned Uri
    }
```

});

**Launching the activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
Button selectButton = findViewById(R.id.select_button);

selectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Pass in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
        // as the input
        mGetContent.launch("image/*");
    }
});
}
```

You can also see the official documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result